# Implementing layout like YouTube for playing a Video

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am trying to implement layout like YouTube to play video , where it can be slide down to bottom and still i can check other videos.

Can you please provide me any links where i can start with. 
Is [SlidingPlaneLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) can be used to Implement this video drag ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this library [DraggablePanel](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel). This library created to build a draggable user interface similar to the new YouTube draggable video component based on Fragments or Views

Comment: i'm using that library and it work on android 2.3 but not correct when you scaling header

Comment: This library is deprecated, and have issues in latest android version.